# jQuery datePicker icon won't show on the xhtml page

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using Primefaces in my XHTML
I decided to use the jQuery's datePicker with icon trigger instead of PrimeFaces calendar on my web page.
the code for the datepicker is :

```
<h:panelGrid id="searchGrid" columns="3" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="one,two,three">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="date" value="Date" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>                  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#date").datepicker({
                    minDate : "#{indexBean.searchCriteria.mindate}",
                    maxDate : "#{indexBean.searchCriteria.maxdate}",
                    dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
                    showOn : "button",
                    buttonImage : "/style/images/calendar.png",
                    buttonImageOnly : true
                });
            });
        </script>
        <p:inputText id="date" value="#{indexBean.searchCriteria.date}" label="Date" validator="#{indexBean.validateDate}">
            <p:watermark value="eg: 01/01/2013" for="date" /> 
        </p:inputText>
```

However the button (icon) of the datePicker won't show on the page.
is there anything missing??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you access the calendar image directly by entering the URL into the browser: `http://localhost:port/yourappcontext/style/images/calendar.png`?

Comment: Yes I can.
I have used another image in the same Xhtml page and it worked
<p:graphicImage id="dateHelp" value="/style/images/help.png" />

Comment: What browser are you using? You should be able to see an error in the console using the browser dev tools.

Comment: Google crome is giving me this error: (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' 
(anonymous function)). Is there anything i could be missing???  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yepeeee
I FIXED IT
Only one tiny small thing i needed to change

## date to .date (in the )

id="date" to styleclass="date" (in the )
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have jQuery UI imported.  Make sure you have something like this in the head of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also, I would move your javascript below the datepicker input element:

```
<h:panelGrid id="searchGrid" columns="3" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="one,two,three">
<p:column>
    <h:outputLabel for="date" value="Date" />
</p:column>
<p:column>                  
    <p:inputText id="date" value="#{indexBean.searchCriteria.date}" label="Date" validator="#{indexBean.validateDate}">
        <p:watermark value="eg: 01/01/2013" for="date" /> 
    </p:inputText>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#date").datepicker({
                minDate : "#{indexBean.searchCriteria.mindate}",
                maxDate : "#{indexBean.searchCriteria.maxdate}",
                dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
                showOn : "button",
                buttonImage : "/style/images/calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly : true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this is part of the page <head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
  href="#{request.contextPath}/style/theme.css"></link>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/style/babl.css"></link>
anything missing??

Comment: You don't have `http://` on the front of the urls in your jQuery stylesheet and javascript includes.

Comment: I think you're having issues with the combination of primefaces with jQuery UI. There are quite a few questions on stackoverflow when I do a google search for "jQuery UI datepicker with primefaces", like this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/12307679/1970746. I don't know much about primefaces so without doing a bunch of research I probably can't help, sorry.

Comment: I did search everywhere before i posted this question. Anyway thanks clav

Comment: Hey guys. I figured out that the icon trigger is not working inside the <h:form>of my page ... How can I make it works??? Thanks

Comment: Right click on the page and do a `view source` after it's rendered in your browser and add the HTML of the form to your question.